# Excel pulling data from certain cells

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-2007

I have a file that I only want to extract cells B9, B19, B29, etc etc etc in a pattern throughout the entire file. I would preferably like it to be extracted to a different excel file or someway so that I can do stuff with only those cells in another excel worksheet.

Potentially, I may have several excel files that I may need to do this sort of thing so if there were a way where I had the same format throughout a lot of files that I could always extract cells B9, B19, B29 that would be great. any help appreciated

I looking for syntax if possible

EDIT

Was thinking if I could somehow make an excel IF statement saying if Row has a 9 in it and the row is B then print it somewhere but I want it printed in a column

**EDIT 2**
I just want column B not A like I mentioned before.
B9, B19,B29,B39 through the whole file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the INDIRECT function. It takes a cell reference as a text string and returns the value in that cell. So instead of using

```
=data!a9
```

to get the value in sheet "data" in cell a9, you use

```
=indirect("data!a9")
```

You can also use r1c1 notation, like this:

```
=indirect("data!r9c1",false)
```

From there you can use the ROW and COLUMN functions to go in steps of 10:

```
=INDIRECT("data!r"&-1+10*ROW()&"c"&COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

If you put this formula in A1 of your output sheet and then copy and paste it down and across, it will give you the values in data!A9, data!A19, data!A29,... in cells A1, A2, A3... Depending on how you want your output arranged, you might have to modify the cell reference string.

Comment: It's giving me an REF error but if I'm wanting to do it in B soooo I need to copy and paste =INDIRECT("data!r"&-1+10*ROW()&"c"&COLUMN(),FALSE) from the top of column B(where there is no data because if i put it in a cell with data it would just overwrite it?)then drag it through the columns?

Comment: If the data you want is on sheet "data" in cells A9, B9, C9, A19,..., and you want the output in sheet "output" in cells A1, B1, C1, A2,..., then put that formula in sheet "output" in cells A1, B1, C1, A2,...

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for all the questions: I'm only wanting values from B9,B19,B29,B39 in that pattern throughout the entire file

Comment: No problem. This should do the trick, since you just need column 2:
    =INDIRECT("DATA!R"&-1+10*ROW()&"C2",FALSE)

Comment: Okay let me explain what it is doing: I want the data on Sheet 1 B9,b19, etc . You're wanting me to put the formula in Sheet 2(aka click the link on the bottom to open another sheet)enter the equation in cell A1 it says #REF! seems like it doesn't know where it is at. sorry i mean to add B0,B9,B19... etc etc

Comment: Are you changing "data" to the name of the sheet where the data actually is? =INDIRECT("Sheet1!r"... instead of =INDIRECT("data!r"...

Comment: okay I changed it from data!r to Sheet1!r but now it just shows the equation and if i click and drag it it only shows the equation however far i drag it

Comment: Nevermind i got it! I had a space in front of the =INDIRECT !! Thanks so much! :) If I could rate this up I would

Comment: Are you missing the "=" at the beginning? or maybe you accidentally hit ctrl-`, which shows formulas instead of values?

Comment: Fixed it. had a space in the front. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to do it with code:

```
Sub Test()
  'Assumes Sheet1 has your values and Sheet2 will be the data extracted from every row ending in 9
  Dim iCounter As Long
  Dim newSheetRow As Long
  Dim aValue As String
  Dim bValue As String

  newSheetRow = 1
  'Start and nine and increment by 10 till you reach end of sheet
  For iCounter = 9 To Sheet1.Rows.Count - 1 Step 10 'NOTE:  You may not want to do it by RowCount, but just showing you could
      aValue = Sheet1.Range("A" & iCounter)
      bValue = Sheet1.Range("B" & iCounter)

      Sheet2.Range("A" & newSheetRow).Value = "We were on row: " & iCounter
      Sheet2.Range("B" & newSheetRow).Value = aValue
      Sheet2.Range("C" & newSheetRow).Value = bValue
      newSheetRow = newSheetRow + 1
  Next iCounter

  MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Jesus...I sure do hope so! :D

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you want to do this depends on how you need to do it, if it's a one of them some simple excel commands might help.

e.g.

In Cell C1 put the following:

```
=MOD(ROW(),10)
```

then replicate this down to the bottom of your data. the command will return the numbers 1 through to 0. You can then filter the data on column C where value is 9 then select the visible rows and copy the data to a new sheet.

```
ROW()  ' this returns the ROW number of cell the command is in.
MOD(number, divisor) ' this basically divides one number by the other and returns the remainder. so row 9 / 10 = 0 remainder of 9, row 19 / 10 = 1 remainder of 9.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The thing is that There are other columns C,D,E which will also have a row associated with Row 9,19,29,39,49,59. I'm unsure if you're answer helps or not because I'm a bit confused if it does what I need it to.

Comment: @Tyler31 I'm guessing you want columns A to E row 9, 19, 29 etc on a new sheet/workbook - if you put the "=mod(row(),10)" in the last column and filter that (eg column F then you can copy just the visible filtered rows to a new sheet/workbook

Comment: I want only column B. B0,B9,B19,B29,B39 etc